# How do I plot a line graph with dots for each data point using MatPlotLib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, linegraph

My desired outcome is a graph that looks like this

```
ax.plot(df.x, df.y, 'b.-')
```

where a line is generated with a dot at every location there is a data point. But I also want specific colors like "lightsteelblue".

When I try plotting

```
ax.plot(df.x, df.y, color='lightsteelblue', ls='.-')
```

a value error comes up that '.-' is not supported with "ls". Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks for your time,
-Bojan

Comment: can you provide a full reproducible code and a schematic of the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

below code should work for you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, np.random.randint(1, 7) , 10)
y = np.linspace(0, np.random.randint(7, 9), 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, y, **{'color': 'lightsteelblue', 'marker': 'o'})

plt.show()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: in addition `markevery=n` can limit the number of markers, one out of n.

Answer (score 4):

The argument `ls` is short for *linestyle*, but you're trying to also pass it a marker style. But to pass a marker style you need to use the `marker` argument, e.g.

```
ax.plot(x, y, color='black', ls='-', marker='.')
```